# Why is match missing from props?

Tags: reactjs

I'm writing my first react application and I wanna use a Switch to show the component corresponding to the route. One of the routes uses a param. The problem is that the match attribute is missing from props so route matching doesn't seem to work (No component is inserted).

When I try to console.log this.props.match it returns undefined.

```js
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Index from './Index';
import Debate from './Debate';

class App extends Component {
    
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props.match); // I get undefined
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/debats" component={Index} />
                    <Route path="/debat/:debateSlug" component={Debate} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default withConfig(App);
```

I want to be able to access the match attribute so that the correct component is displayed.

Comment: you haven't passed any props to the `App` component, that why it's undefined

Comment: The `Debate` component gets a param. Your `console.log(this.props.match);` is in the `App` component.

Comment: Hi Vodros, you can access `match` as a property passed down to a component from `react-router-dom` in many way, but, it's not a standard to make such a thing on your default `App`, can you explain these: `1. what are you trying to achieve?` `2. can you explain `withConfig(App)`?`

Answer (score 1):

Add to this in your Component

`import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';`

`export default withRouter(withConfig(App));`

Comment: // I cannot understand about withConfig (what is this?)